# Alternative to CSS in body tag?

Tags: php, css

In my login system in my site I wanted the user's selected CSS to be loaded after validation was complete. The only problem is that my PHP is located in the body element and I ECHOed the  user's CSS link there. I know this is "bad", but what else can I do?

```
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
ECHO $_SESSION['style'];
}
else
{
ECHO 'green';
}
ECHO ".css' />";
```

The PHP script echos some text in the body after the user is logged in, this is why I cannot put the PHP script in the header.

Comment: That depends on how your login system is coded.

Comment: From your description, I'm not clear on what exactly you're doing. Could you show us the part of your code where the "PHP is located in the body element" and where the CSS link is?

Comment: Why not add php tag in head too ?

Comment: You have no access to the HEAD?

Comment: *"I can't put the PHP in the head because the script needs to echo other text in the body."* that makes no sense to me

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarity. The PHP script echos some text in the body after the user is logged in, this is why I cannot put the PHP script in the header. Does that make sense?

Comment: no. it's your file you can put php any where in it you like.

Comment: You don't seem to understand. The php is in the body because it needs to echo text at a certain point on the page. This is why the php file is at the certain point on the page. If I put it in the header it would echo in the wrong spot.

Comment: How is the rest of your page created? Just handle the css where you need to. I'm *very* confused as to why this is an issue at all. If PHP is working in the `body` of your document, it will work in the `head` as well.

Comment: My code works fine, but many people say it's "taboo" or "bad" to put a css anchor in the body of an html document. The PHP is in the body because it's echoing text in the body. Am I missing something obvious here or why is everyone confused?

Comment: *You* Don't understand. See my answer.

Comment: you are not limited to one php script in one html file, i have no idea how you structured things, but clearly you don't understand how this works.

Comment: Alright, there's a lot of miscommunication going on. We're thinking completely different things. You are trying to say the best approach is to use a php function in the body to trigger the printing of the CSS in the header? Sounds good.

Comment: Please see my answer for a little clarity. I think we understand what you're trying to do better than you do. Please comment on my answer for further discussion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could use some jQuery to append the style in the `<head>`:

```
$(head).append('<style><?php echo user_css ?></style>');
```

Comment: Hmm, a bit messy, how would I go about triggering the jQuery from my PHP? Also can jQuery access session variables?

Comment: @user1688679 you would use `$(function() {}):` which triggers automaticly when document is fully loaded into browser.

Comment: So could I just submit the session variable to the jQuery as well? Like $(function($_SESSION['style']) {}):?

Comment: Why not just inject PHP in the header to parse the tag. This is such a roundabout hack to make something work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm under the assumption that you're not at all familiar with the basics of PHP, so I'll break it down as simply as I can. If your document is able to execute PHP (which it sounds like it can because you have things happening in the body), all you need to do is wrap the PHP code with `<?php` and `?>` for it to parse *as* PHP.

You shouldn't put stylesheets inside your body. Indeed, that is something that no one will recommend. What you can do, however, is execute PHP in the head of your document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
  <head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <title>title</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  
<?php
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='{$_SESSION['user_css']}'>";
?>
    <script src="script.js"></script>  
  </head>  
  <body>  
<?php
echo 'body text';
?>
  </body>  
</html>
```

It doesn't matter *where* you decide to inject PHP code into your document, it will render as you wish. I'd suggest an MVC solution, but if this is just a small, one-off file, feel free to inject PHP wherever you want it, as often as you need it.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Answer (score 0):

You can load the user css after the document is loaded using jQuery.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(head).append('<style>
  <?php echo($user_css); ?>
  </style>');

});

</script>
```

Though just adding a section to output the CSS in the head would be easier to maintain in the future and doesn't need the page to load. A dramatic enough change on a slow(ish) connection and the user will see the flicker as the CSS loads their style.

Comment: Hmm. Alright. It's just a personal site so it won't matter too much if the CSS lags momentarily.